# .htacces rewrite rule with pagination

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, pagination

A clients wordpress site requires some rewrite rules due to some issues with a theme they are using and the hosting setup, currently I have one which is:

```
RewriteRule ^events index.php?pagename=events [L]
```

So when I go to `www.site.com/events` it'll show me `www.site.com/index.php?pagename=events`

This works fine, however the theme they are using on their events page will show pagination links, which produces links like:

```
www.site.com/events/?page_id_all=2
```

Which because of the previous rewrite rule, will still just show

```
www.site.com/index.php?pagename=events
```

How do I get this type of link, with a variable `page_id_all` to resolve to `www.site.com/index.php?pagename=events&page_id_all=$`

So far my research and experimentation hasn't returned any answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [QSA](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag in your rule.

```
RewriteRule ^events index.php?pagename=events [QSA,L]
```